# How to download a image from default docker registry?

Tags: docker, registry

I'm trying to download a container image from default registry with the command:

```
docker run -d --name=nginx -p 80:80 nginx:alpine
```

The output is:

Unable to find image 'nginx:alpine' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
See 'docker run --help'.

I already configured the proxy with cntlm. I'm behind a corporate firewall with Deep Inspection Package (DIP, man in the middle)

Could I define the default registry (https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/)  like a insecure registry? How? There are another solution?
I already try the options:

```
--insecure-registry=registry-1.docker.io:5000 
--insecure-registry=registry-1.docker.io 
--insecure-registry='*'
--insecure-registry=https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
```

Comment: Did you do all the proxy steps documented here https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/?

Comment: Yes, I already do these steps. The content of my  /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf is:
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1"

This configuration works in part, apparently doker can reach the registry, but because of the corporate firewall it can't validate the signed content from the registry.

Comment: If you run `docker info`, does it show the registry servers in the insecure list?

Comment: Resolved! Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved.

My SO is mint (based in ubuntu xenial) and docker version 17.06.0-ce

To resolve I needed do put the root certificate from my company's firewall to my linux ca-certificates (reference 1 - https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate). Obs.: Proxy already configured using cntlm (reference 2 - http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) (reference 3 - https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/)

First I exported the certicate installed in my browser, google chrome. From chrome a choose configuration->advanced->privacy and security->manage certificates->trusted root certificate authorities, so I selected the authority, in my case something like mycompany.com. After, I choose export->advance, select X.509 base64 format (*.cer). The correct format is very important. I saved the file ~/certificate.crt.
Create a extra directory:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
```

copy the certificate to extra dir:

```
sudo cp ~/certificate.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
```

update ca-certificates config:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

restart docker:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Now docker can download images from default registry.

Comment: the file certificate.cer must be certificate.crt for the command dpkg-reconfigure to work